# How to reference hpp files for OpenCV with NDK?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I can't get my project to open OpenCV's header files:

[image]

However, I can see that OpenCV runs alright (if I comment out those includes) by calling `OpenCVLoader.initDebug()` in `onCreate()`:

[image]

I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18971498/1181261) that you need to edit *Android.mk* which I don't have in the first place. So what am I missing?

---

**EDIT** (3 hours later):

Ok, So I figured out how to include .hpp files I added this to the end of `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include_directories("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include"
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/opencv"
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/opencv2"
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/opencv2/core"
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/opencv2/features2d"
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/opencv2/imgproc")

    add_library(opencv_core STATIC IMPORTED)
    set_target_properties(opencv_core PROPERTIES
        IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/prebuilt/libs/armeabi/libopencv_core.a)

    add_library(opencv_imgproc STATIC IMPORTED)
    set_target_properties(opencv_imgproc PROPERTIES
        IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/prebuilt/libs/armeabi/libopencv_imgproc.a)

    add_library(opencv_features2d STATIC IMPORTED)
    set_target_properties(opencv_features2d PROPERTIES
        IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/prebuilt/libs/armeabi/libopencv_features2d.a)
```

Now I get `undefined reference` errors when linking:

```
> Build command failed.
Error while executing 'C:\Users\kfjier\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\cmake\3.6.3155560\bin\cmake.exe' with arguments {--build E:\Dropbox\Freelance\BowlingOpenCV\Bowlingtrainer\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\mips64 --target native-lib}
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library ..\obj\mips64\libnative-lib.so
FAILED: cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\kfjier\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe  -target mips64el-none-linux-android -gcc-toolchain C:/Users/kfjier/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/mips64el-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/kfjier/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-mips64 -fPIC -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti  -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libnative-lib.so -o ..\obj\mips64\libnative-lib.so CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o  -llog -lm "C:/Users/kfjier/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/mips64/libgnustl_static.a" && cd ."
CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o: In function `Java_eu_codehunter_bowlingtrainer_MainActivity_FindFeatures':
  E:\Dropbox\Freelance\BowlingOpenCV\Bowlingtrainer\app\src\main\cpp/native-lib.cpp:18: undefined reference to `cv::FastFeatureDetector::create(int, bool, int)'
  E:\Dropbox\Freelance\BowlingOpenCV\Bowlingtrainer\app\src\main\cpp/native-lib.cpp:19: undefined reference to `cv::noArray()'
  E:\Dropbox\Freelance\BowlingOpenCV\Bowlingtrainer\app\src\main\cpp/native-lib.cpp:23: undefined reference to `cv::circle(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::Point_<int>, int, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int, int, int)'
  clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

I think the cv::FastFeatureDetector class belongs to libopencv_features2d.a and cv::circle() function belongs to libopencv_highgui.a. So you have to include those libraries. An simpler way is to add single libopencv_java3.so as shared library which inlcudes all the OpenCV library.